# How do I wrap a timezone adjustment to the date command in a string?

Tags: shell-script, date, timezone

I'm trying to output the date and time, in a different time zone, in a bash shell script. Following [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/48101/how-can-i-have-date-output-the-time-from-a-different-timezone), I did this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

IL=":Asia/Jerusalem" date "+%a %b %d %R"
echo "Israel:    $IL"
```

which outputs this:

```
Wed Jun 19 15:12
Israel:
```

Not only is the time incorrect for that time zone, but the output is incorrectly displayed on two lines.

I'd like it to output this:

```
Israel: Wed Jun 19 23:12
```

In other scripts, where the default time zone is fine (for example, in my `.xinitrc` to display the current system time), I've done:

```
date_str="$(date +"%a %b %d %R")";
topbar="Time: $date_str";
xsetroot -name "$top_bar";
```

What am I doing wrong this time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You left out the `TZ=` part which will assign the timezone to the `TZ` environment variable for the `date` command:

```
TZ='Asia/Jerusalem' date '+%a %b %d %R'
```

The question you linked has a very detailed explanation of this.

In order to assign this output to a variable you need to use [command substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Command-Substitution):

```
IL=$(TZ='Asia/Jerusalem' date '+%a %b %d %R')
```